# C# System.AggregateException has been thrown

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I am currently working on a console application that uses the Last10kAPI to retrieve financial data from various documents that they provide but whenever I build the application it compiles and opens up the terminal I get a weird error saying "System.AggregateException has been thrown.One or more errors occurred. (Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference)" For the sake of simplicity I some of my code from my Program.cs below. The formatting is a bit off when adding it to stackoverflow so just assume proper indentation. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance!

```
class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RunAsync().Wait();
        Console.WriteLine("Financial Data from Ratios, Balance Sheet, Cash Flow, and Income Statement");
    }


    static private async Task RunAsync()
    {
        //Grab our ticker List;
        List<string> tickers = new List<string>();
        tickers = await GetTickers();

        //Grab ratios for all companies in ticker list and store the results in a list of Ratios
        List<Ratios> ratiosfortickers = new List<Ratios>();
        foreach (string ticker in tickers)
        {
            Ratios tempRatio = new Ratios();
            tempRatio = await GetRatio(ticker);
            ratiosfortickers.Add(tempRatio);
        }

        //Grab all balance sheet
        List<BalanceSheets> balancesheetfortickers = new List<BalanceSheets>();
        foreach (string ticker in tickers)
        {

            BalanceSheets tempBalanceSheets = new BalanceSheets();
            tempBalanceSheets = await GetBalanceSheet(ticker);
            //balancesheetsfortickers.Add(tempBalanceSheets);

        }

        //Grab all Cash Flow
        List<CashFlows> cashflowsfortickers = new List<CashFlows>();
        foreach (string ticker in tickers)
        {
            CashFlows tempCashFlow = new CashFlows();
            tempCashFlow = await GetCashFlows(ticker);
            cashflowsfortickers.Add(tempCashFlow);
        }



        //Grab all Income Statement
        List<Income> incomefortickers = new List<Income>();
        foreach (string ticker in tickers)
        {
            Income tempIncome = new Income();
            tempIncome = await GetIncome(ticker);
            incomefortickers.Add(tempIncome);
        }
    }

}


  }
```

Comment: What do you expect people to do with this much code? Please create a minimal example and describe where the error is thrown.

Comment: AggregateException has an `InnerExceptions` collection property that contains the exception(s) that led to the AggregateException. Look at them and their stack trace(!) and you will (likely) know which code line caused the problem...

Comment: You have [too much code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/). You need to narrow the problem down to a [Minimal Complete Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Doing this will not only help us, it will help you understand what is causing the problem; you may even be able to solve it before even needing to ask for help.

Comment: Use `async Task Main` and the `await` operator. If you don't have the latest C#, use `GetAwaiter`. The `AggregateException` is a failure to unwrap.